# On the proof of the unsolvability of the word problem in semigroups

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, recursion, computability, turing-machines

I'm trying to understand the following proof of the unsolvability of the word problem in semigroups. I tried to reproduce the proof from some kind of personal communication, so I'm not sure everything is very precise/correct, and I have some questions about it (they are at the end).

> First, some notation. We say that the Turing machine with tape
> alphabet $\{a_1,\dots, a_n\}$ and set of states $\{q_0,\dots,q_m\}$
> ($q_1$ is the initial state, $q_0$ is the terminal state) is in
> configuration $AqxB$ if the machine is in state $q$, its head points
> at the cell with the symbol $x$, and to the left of that cell is the
> word $A$, to the right of that cell is word $B$.
>
> An instruction of the form $q_ia_j\to q_ra_sR$ results in the
> following change of configuration: $Aq_ia_j\to Aa_sq_r(bB')$ where
> $bB'$ is the word $B$ with the first letter "separated" from the
> remainder of the word. Similarly, if we have an instruction like
> $q_ia_k\to q_ra_sL$, then the configuration changes as follows:
> $Aq_ia_jB\to A'q_raa_sB$ where $A=A'a$.
>
> Now the proof. We construct the following semigroup.
>
> - Generators: $a_1,\dots,a_n,q_1,\dots,q_m, \lhd, \rhd$
> - Relations (in orange boxes):
>
> [image]
>
> Claim. $q_1X=q_0$ iff the machine halts on input $X$.
>
> Suppose the machine halts on $X$. So the initial configuration is
> $q_1(xX')$ where $X=xX'$ (or $q_1X$ for short). To every
> configuration, there corresponds a word. If one configuration changes
> to another, then the corresponding words are equal (here we're using
> the relations in the first four boxes, I guess). Suppose the machine
> halts in configuration $Aq_0a_jA'$ where $A,A'$ are some words. Then
> we can successively apply the relations from the last box and the
> result will be $q_0$ (the empty tape, and the head points to some
> empty cell).  Since there is a chain of equalities verifying that
> $q_1X$ equals $q_0$, this implication is proved.
>
> Conversely, suppose $q_1X=q_0$. If we knew that the chain of
> equalities witnessing $q_1X=q_0$ only uses the relations "from left to
> right", then this would correspond to the run of the machine on input
> $X$ and eventually halting. So it suffices to prove that there is such
> a chain. Consider the shortest chain witnessing $q_1X=q_0$. We show
> that it cannot have instances of "right-to-left" applications of the
> relations. Assume the converse. Consider the last such instance of
> "right-to-left" application. For example, consider the relation in the
> first box above. Then $Pa_sq_ra_kQ=Pq_ia_ja_kQ$. The next instance of
> the application of relations must be "left-to-right":
> $Pq_ia_ja_kQ=Pa_sq_ra_kQ$. In sum, we have
> $Pa_sq_ra_kQ=Pq_ia_ja_kQ=Pa_sq_ra_kQ$, which is "trivial", so it can
> be thrown away from the chain. This contradicts to the minimality of
> the chain.

First, why do we need to add these $\lhd, \rhd$ in the list of generators (and the corresponding relations)? For example, what bad would have happened if we replaced the relation from the second box, namely $q_ia_j\lhd=a_sq_r\#\lhd$, to just $q_ia_j=a_sq_r$ or $q_ia_j\#=a_sq_r\#$? Why do we need to signify that nothing will ever appear to the right (except $\#$)? A specific example of something bad happening would be great, as I didn't understand "in general terms" why we need these.

Second, in the last paragraph, after we considered the last instance of "right-to-left" application of the relations, why is the next application of the relation $Pq_ia_ja_kQ=Pa_sq_ra_kQ$? I understand that it must be "left-to-right", but why are we applying exactly this relation? If we applied some other "left-to-right" relation instead, then we wouldn't get the trivial relation anymore.

Also, general comments, edits, or suggestions about this proof are welcome too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly an inconsistency -- you swap the meanings of $q_0$ and $q_1$ relative to initial and final states. The meaning consistent with the drawing (presumably the most difficut bit to edit) is that $q_0$ is the final state, which means the error is in the first quoted paragraph, and what is written after the drawing is correct.

Regarding your first question, if we take your suggestion of $q_{i}a_{j}=a_{s}q_{r}$, then we would have to add an extra relation interpreting the action performed when we are in state $q_{r}$ and reading the blank symbol: that is, if there is a instruction $q_r\#\to q_ta_kR$ we need a relation $q_r=a_kq_t$ (and a corresponding relation if our instruction moves left). So that's a bit of a non-starter; the change we had made would mean we'd have to write down two more relations in any case.

Likewise, if we take your suggestion of $q_ia_j\#=a_sq_r\#$, we would again need an extra relation interpreting the possibility that  we will move right when $q_r$ reads the blank symbol, as this would requre us to rustle up an additional blank symbol that isn't currently present in our word, so it wouldn't be covered by any of the possibilities we already have written down. That is, if there is a instruction $q_r\#\to q_ta_kR$ we need a relation $q_r\#=a_kq_t\#$. So for us, the symbol $\lhd$ manages to play the role of an infinitely inexhaustible supply of blank symbols; when we encounter it we pop one off the front, and keep the remaining infinitely many remaining condensed into the one symbol (since of course we cannot write the infinitely many symbols down). The way it is written allows us to deal with the special behaviour of "the last symbol on the tape" in a succint way.

Now regarding your second question, I guess the missing observation here is that, as no relation increases the number of $q$-terms that appear, we know there is no other $q_t$ appearing anywhere in our word except for the single $q_i$ we're interested in. Then furthermore as we know there is a instruction $q_ia_j\to q_ra_sR$, we know there is no *other* instruction $q_ia_j\to\text{anything}$, and furthermore we make only left-to-right applications by assumption. So the only relation that can apply is the one that undoes what we just did.

The only other thing for a general comment, edit or suggestion is what happens if the instruction for $q_1x$ (where $X=xX'$) tells you to move left. You could of course use $\rhd q_1X$ instead ;)

Comment: Sorry for the late comment. You're right about the typo, I've fixed it. Regarding your penultimate paragraph, why do we know that there is instruction $q_ia_j\to a_ra_sR$? Also, what part of my question are you referring to in your last paragraph?

Comment: What we've said (in your quoted paragraph) is suppose the last "right-to-left" relation we've used is the one in the first orange box. This relation only exists in the semigroup we've defined if there's instruction $q_i a_j\rightarrow a_r a_s R$; that's what it says on the blue-highlighted line directly above the orange box. If we'd used a different relation, it would mean the corresponding instruction which made that relation exist in the semigroup must exist.

Comment: The last comment refers to the statement of the claim. What if there is instruction $q_1 x\rightarrow q_r a_s L$ (where $x$ is the first symbol of the input i.e. $X=xX'$)? We have no relation that applies so we're stuck. This is simply because we've forgotten that we must denote blank tape by a symbol

Comment: Thanks, I got the first point. By the way, do we need to consider 4 cases (when considering the first relation that applies "from right to left"), viz. the first 4 relations? Or do we also need to consider the relations at the bottom? If we need to consider them too, it's not even clear which is the "right hand side" in them, since they are written as a  chain. Regarding the second point, I thought the third and fourth rules cover all instructions like $q_lx\to q_ra_sL$, in particular for $l=1$? So I'm not sure I understood this.

Comment: I suppose we would need to add in a little detail like "if we are not yet in state $q_0$, then...", and we use the argument as given, so we consider 4 cases (although we can really do a "without loss of generality" argument and handle them all at once). Once we are in state $q_0$ (– that is, once we have established a chain of equalities inside our semigroup witnessing that $q_1X=Aq_0 aB$ (– really I should say $\triangleright q_1X=Aq_0 aB$)) then it is easy to show $Aq_0 aB=q_0$. So the more elaborate argument is only needed before this stage, so it is just the first four cases.

Comment: For the second point, suppose I have a Turing machine with two states $\{q_0,q_1\}$, alphabet with one symbol $a$, and one instruction $q_1 a\rightarrow q_0 aL$. This machine halts on input $a$, however we cannot prove that in the semigroup we define from it, that $q_1 a=q_0$ – there simply is no relation that says $q_1 a$ is equal to _anything_ else. We can of course say that $\triangleright q_1 a=\triangleright q_0\#a$, at which point the final relations clear everything up. It's a minor detail, but has reminded me we also will need to append $\triangleleft$ to the end of the input $X$.

Comment: Thanks I got your points. So is it assumed that the $a_i$s listed in the the set of generators don't contain $\#$? And $\#$ should be listed as a separate generator? If $\#$ was allowed to occur among the $a_i$s, then the third relation could be read as $\# q_ia_j=q_r\# a_s$; and if so, then in your example, we could write $q_1a $ as $\# q_1a$, and we could have applied the above relation.

Comment: Maybe there's another point that I don't fully understand: the yellow cells are supposed to be filled with blanks only. But what about the cells that are not yellow and that are not filled with anything? Can they contain arbitrary stuff, or are they supposed to contain only blanks too?